# Node js csurf token always invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

I have installed the csurf package on a Node.js Exspress app. The token is displaying in the form correctly (it seems), with `name="_csrf"` and value equal to some hash value, that was set with `req.csrfToken()`. But I always get an error saying that the token was invalid. Here is some of my code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var session = require('express-session')
var service = require('./service')
var csrf = require('csurf')

app.set('view engine', 'html')
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
})

app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Blue Dragon',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }))
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)
    res.status(403)
    res.send('session has expired or form tampered with')
})
```

and:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = module.exports = express()
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks')
var service = require('../../service')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
})

var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.get('/getnoun/:id', function (req, res) {
    req.models.noun.find({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, noun) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
            service.log('Critical', err.message)
        }
        res.render('noun', { nouns: noun })
    })
})

app.get('/addnoun', function (req, res) {
    res.render('addnoun', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

//app.post('/savenoun', function (req, res) { // gives same problem both ways
app.post('/savenoun', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
    var noun = new req.models.noun({
        lemma : req.body.lemma,
        gloss : req.body.gloss,
        sentence : req.body.sentence,
        gender : req.body.gender,
        roman : req.body.roman,
        img : req.body.img,
        level : req.body.level
    })

    noun.save(function (err) {
        if (err)  {
            throw err
            service.log('Critical', err.message)
        }
    })

    res.render('home')
})
```

in the html: (I viewed source to make sure a value was put in the hidden input)

```
<form action="/savenoun" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="lemma" placeholder="lemma"><br>
    <input type="text" name="gloss" placeholder="gloss"><br>
    <input type="text" name="roman" placeholder="roman"><br>
    <input type="text" name="sentence" placeholder="sentence"><br>
    <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="gender"><br>
    <input type="text" name="img" placeholder="image"><br>
    <input type="text" name="level" placeholder="level"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skyblue">Save</button>
</form>
```

Why isn't the csrf token getting validated right?

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed to post video links here, but there is a perfect explanation of using csrf protection [watch me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waAqEjjssxU&list=PL55RiY5tL51rajp7Xr_zk-fCFtzdlGKUp&index=7) starting from minute 5

Comment: Didn't you forget to add this `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">` inside your form?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code from csurf npm package.

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// create express app
var app = express()

// parse cookies
// we need this because "cookie" is true in csrfProtection
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World !!! ')
});

app.get('/form', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  res.send({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err)

  // handle CSRF token errors here
  res.status(403)
  res.send('form tampered with')
})

var port = 3000;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is listening at: ', port);
```

Sample Request

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/form',
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     Connection: 'keep-alive',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     cookie: '_csrf=uQmzsYUSlBObB62SJIC_z7tt',
     Host: 'localhost:3000',
     'Postman-Token': 'b25b248a-319c-4429-be73-b8f0d1d08efc,3768fe7b-4d1f-4486-a40d-107609f97258',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     Accept: '*/*',
     'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.13.0' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

and

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/process',
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     Connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     cookie: '_csrf=uQmzsYUSlBObB62SJIC_z7tt',
     Host: 'localhost:3000',
     'Postman-Token': '2c3d2ee3-8678-4cef-a926-48866083112f,016ab945-a9fb-4fa9-95a7-e62f934414bb',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     Accept: '*/*',
     'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.13.0',
     'CSRF-Token': '0zMVtG9B-OEI4ZD_9meo9EiWpPkOfngwRWkU' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```